# Can't add comments or start bounty while using Firefox 22

Tags: support, comments, bounties, firefox

I am having problems with Firefox version 22. When I got to my question and try to add a comment or start a bounty either nothing happens or it jumps me to the top of the page.

Firebug shows this error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=5d233283ca8d
Line 5
```

Don't have problems in Chrome or IE.

Not sure if that is the problem or something else.

Comment: have you added any extensions or user scripts?